# Doesn't this defy the rules of static variables?

Tags: java, static-variables

I have declared a static variable and am changing its value through a non-static method by invoking it in the Initializer block which will be invoked every time an object is instantiated. Why does this not give me run time or compile time error?

```
public class FinalKeyWord {

    final int age;
    static int name;

    {
        ran();
        displayName();
    }


    public FinalKeyWord() {
        this.age = 10;
    }

    public FinalKeyWord(int a){
        this.age = a;
    }

    void ran(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int rand = r.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println(rand);
        name = rand;
    }

    public void displayAge() {
        System.out.println("This is final " + age);
    }

    public void displayName() {
        System.out.println("This is static " + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FinalKeyWord a = new FinalKeyWord();
        //a.displayAge();
        //a.displayName();
        FinalKeyWord a2 = new FinalKeyWord(35);
        //a2.displayName();

    }

}
```

Output:

```
    This is static 2 \n
    This is is static 3
```

Comment: but why could not an instance modify a static value??

Comment: Why do you think that you shouldn't be able to access a static field from an instance of the class?

Comment: "Why does this not give me run time or compile time error?". Why should it ?

Comment: `static` and `final` are two separate concepts. What exactly is it that you're confused about?

Answer (score 1):

a variable being static doesn't mean that you can't change its value later, it means that its allocated once in memory for all instances of the class its in, so whenever you create an new object it will point to the same block in memory for this variable unlike normal variables or instance variables where a new block in memory will be reserved for this variable whenever a new object of this class is created.

Answer (score 0):

From [Java Documentation/Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html),

**Instance methods can access class variables and class methods directly.** 
So this is perfectly legal,

```
public class FinalKeyWord {

    static int a = 5;

    void change() {
        a= 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FinalKeyWord obj = new FinalKeyWord();
        System.out.println(a);
        obj.change();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

And will print,

```
5
10
```

Comment: I would argue that _Java Documentation_ is the header and are itself provided by Oracle but never mind.

Comment: Yes, Java _Documentation_, but Java docs is something specific.

Comment: Another helpful link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-26-the-initializer-block-in-java/